# Add icon before form field

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop

How can I add icons before the form fields?

This is how looks now:
[image: here]

And here how I want:
[image: here]

**Here is css code (front.css):**

```css
body .qb-form {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 660px) {
  body .qb-form {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

body .qb-form h2 {
  background: #3482C3;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 0;
}

body .qb-form .moreinfo {
  background: #3482C3;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

body .qb-form label {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

body .qb-form .qb-gdpr-label {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

body .qb-form .quickbuy_input {
  height: 31px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid #ABADB3;
  padding: 5px;
}

body .qb-form textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #abadb3;
}

body .qb-form .crow {
  padding: 0 25px 25px 25px;
}

body .qb-form .buttons_wrp {
  padding: 10px 25px 25px 25px;
}

body .qb-form .buttons_wrp .button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: #3482C3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .qb-form .buttons_wrp .qb-btn-submit {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 62px;
  background: #3482C3 url('../img/cart-icon.png') no-repeat 15px center;
}

body .qb-form .buttons_wrp .button:hover {
  background-color: #388bd1;
}

body .qb-wrp .qb-btn span {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}

.product-simple .qb-btn {
  background: none;
  color: #1F679B;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #1F679B;
  padding: 0 0 1px 0;
}

body .qb-form sup {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

body .qb-form .quickbuy_errors,
body .qb-form .quickbuy_success {
  margin: 0 15px;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body .qb-form .qb-product-name {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

body .qb-form body .qb-form_loader {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}

body .qb-form .qb-loader {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body .qb-form .qb-loader.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.qb-form .qb-gdpr-label .qb_gdpr_wrp {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.qb-form .qb-btn-close {
  display: none;
}

.qb-form .qb-btn-close span {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  border: none;
}

.qb-gdpr-label p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .qb-wrap,
  #product .qb-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

**And here is the hook.tpl:**

```html
<div class="crow">
  <label for="quickbuy_name">{l s='Your name' mod='quickbuy'}:</label>
  <input type="text" class="qb_name qb-input-field form-control" id="quickbuy_name" name="qb_customer_name" value="{$qb_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
</div>

<div class="crow">
  <label for="quickbuy_address">{l s='Your address' mod='quickbuy'}:</label>
  <input type="text" class="qb_address qb-input-field form-control" id="quickbuy_address" name="qb_address" value="{$qb_address|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
</div>

<div class="crow">
  <label for="quickbuy_phone">{l s='Your phone number' mod='quickbuy'}: <sup>*</sup></label>
  <input type="text" class="qb_phone qb-input-field form-control" id="quickbuy_phone" name="qb_phone" value="{$qb_phone|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
</div>

{if $qb_gdpr}
<div class="crow">
  <label class="qb-gdpr-label">
    <span class="qb_gdpr_wrp">
        <input type="checkbox" class="qb_gdpr" name="qb_gdpr">
    </span>
    {if $qb_gdpr_text}
        {$qb_gdpr_text nofilter}{* HTML *}
    {else}
        {l s='I agree to processing of my personal data' mod='quickbuy'}
        {if $qb_gdpr_link}(<a target="_blank" href="{$qb_gdpr_link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{l s='read' mod='quickbuy'}</a>){/if}
    {/if}
  </label>
</div>
{/if}

<div class="crow quickbuy_errors error"></div>
<div class="crow quickbuy_success success"></div>

<div class="buttons_wrp">
  <input type="hidden" name="qb_id_product" value="{$qb_product->id|intval}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="qb_id_product_attribute" value="{$qb_product->id_product_attribute|intval}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="qb_token" value="{$qb_token|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="qb_action" value="submitQB" />
  <input type="submit" class="qb-btn-submit btn btn-default button button-small" value="{l s='Buy' mod='quickbuy'}" />
  <button class="qb-btn-close btn btn-default button button-small"><span>&times;</span> {l s='Close' mod='quickbuy'}</button>
  <img class="qb-loader" src="/img/loader.gif" alt="{l s='Loading...' mod='quickbuy'}" />
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I will be happy if anyone can help.
Thank you in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Which part are you stuck at exactly? The question is a bit broad

Answer (score 0):

You can select the input fields from your HTML template by using their id's.

You you use [icons8](https://icons8.com/icons/set/mail) to find the correct icons.
There you can get the *Link (CDN)* for each item by clicking on the *download* button and *copy HTML*.

You can paste the copied code in your HTML (just before the respective input field).

Afterwards you can style the respective item in your CSS file.
So that it has the same border and height as your input field.